# В каких случаях ставится тире перед...

Tags: пунктуация

В каких случаях нужно ставить тире перед КАК и перед СЛОВНО?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Постановка тире никак не связана со словами "как" или "словно".
Такое может произойти, если тире требуется по общим условиям его постановки. 
Правила постановки тире тут:
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=tire

На большинство этих правил можно привести примеры, в которых после тире оказалось бы слова "как" или "словно".
Вот например:

*§ 171. Тире ставится между предложениями, не соединенными посредством союзов, если второе предложение заключает в себе результат или вывод из того, о чем говорится в первом, например: 

Хвалы приманчивы – как их не пожелать? (Крылов)...*

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, если и этот ответ вызовет претензии по форме, то мне впору будет уходлить с проекта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!